# Find optimal route in farm land-dynamic programming/Dijkstra's

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, dijkstra

I was trying to solve a question on InterviewStreet (the competition has since ended). The problem is to build a ditch from a pond to a farm, given a N*M grid of elevations. The pond and the farm are one of the tiles within the N*M grid and won't be the same tile.

The elevations are numbers between 0 and 9. Additionally, you are given the coordinates of the pond and the farm (1-indexed, row followed by column), which each take up exactly one tile on the grid. You are to write a program that, given this data, computes the minimum cost to build an irrigation ditch.

More specifically, the input that will be fed into your program will be formatted as follows:

N M

pondLocationX pondLocationY

farmLocationX farmLocationY

elevationX1Y1elevationX1Y2...elevationX1YM

elevationX2Y1elevationX2Y2...elevationX2YM

.

.

.

elevationXNY1elevationXNY2...elevationXNYM

where pondLocationX and farmLocationX are integers in the interval [1, N], and pondLocationY and farmLocationY are integers in the interval [1, M], and all  elements are integers in the interval [0, 9]. Note that a single space separates the X and Y coordinates of the farm and pond, but there are no spaces separating the elevations.

Given such an input, your program should print out the minimum cost to build an irrigation ditch from the pond to the farm. The constraints are as follows. The pond and farm will not be at the same location. The elevation of all tiles except for the pond can be increased or decreased at a cost of one for every unit of change (you may leave the elevation the same for a cost of 0). N and M will each be at most 300. After paying for any excavation that is necessary, you can build a ditch at 0 additional cost if there is a sequence of tiles starting at the pond and ending at the farm such that the following are true:

1. (Contiguous path) Each tile in the sequence is adjacent to the previous tile (no diagonal adjacency -- tiles in the interior of the map have exactly 4 adjacent tiles)
2. (Downhill path) Each tile in the sequence, including the pond and farm, has an elevation that is at most that of the previous tile in the sequence.

For example, if the input is the following:

3 5

1 1

3 4

27310

21171

77721

then we can build an irrigation ditch at a cost of just 4, since it suffices to lower the tile at location (1, 3) from 3 to 1 (cost 2), raise the tile at position (1, 5) from 0 to 1 (cost 1), and lower the farm, which is at location (3, 4), from 2 to 1 (cost 1). Note that you cannot travel diagonally to get from (2, 3) to (3, 4) in one step.

Solution:

I think this is a variation of the Djikstra's algorithm, i.e. use the farm as the source node, and stop when you calculate the shortest path to the pond. The "adjacent" tiles are your neighbours, and your edge weights are the differences in your elevations.

However, since you can modify the weights in two ways i.e. if you are higher than your neighbour, then you can either 1) decrease your height to match your neighbour's or 2) increase your neighbour's height to match yours. This effect can percolate outwards and I'm not able to capture this in the algorithm.

How can I adjust Djikstra's algorithm to acommodate for the fact that the weights can be changed?

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: Well the last paragraph states it, just the Dijkstra algorithm doesn't seem to suffice, how do I model the algorithm to capture the fact that morphing the nodes will affect the functioning of the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Dijkstra algorithm on the 3D grid N*M*10. Two vertices (x,y,z) and (x',y',z') are connected (with an oriented arc) if (x,y) and (x',y') are adjacent and z' is not greater than z. The cost on the arc is given by the difference between z' and the initial height at (x',y'). Then find the shortedst path from the pond (with its initial length) to the farm (even if the z coordinate is not the same.

It is possible that the minimal path finded in this way passes two times on the same point (x,y). For example it could pass first from (x,y,z') and then from (x,y,z''). But if this happens you can remove the path from (x,y,z') to (x,y,z'') since replacing (x,y,z') with (x,y,z'') costs equal or less then the path from (x,y,z') to (x,y,z''). So you can assume that for every point (x,y) the path uses only a single value of z.

So the path you have found is the solution to the given problem.

Comment: I am not sure how this will work. For ex. consider the following 3*3 grid: 2 7 1, 1 10  12, 7 8 11. Assume the pond is (1,1) -> height = 2 and the farm is (1,3) -> height =1. I need to consider (1,2) by decreasing its height from 7 to 2, so that cost is 5. If I consider only tiles with height < 2, then I can consider only (2,1) but then overall cost to farm will increase.

Comment: Could you explain your solution with respect to the example given in the question? For example, we raise the height of (1,5) from 0->1, even though water would have flown from (1,4) to (1,5) without this change. How does your solution capture this?

Comment: In my solution you consider all possible heights at position (1,5) in particular you consider z=1.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Could you explain this better, perhaps with a diagram or a visualization. I'm unable to wrap my head around this solution.